# SQL: How to add values according to index columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql table which looks like the following:

```
|value|   |position| |relates_to_position| |type|
 100  |       2    |        NULL         |    1
  50  |       6    |        NULL         |    2
  20  |       7    |           6         |    3
```

From this I need to create the resulting table, which adds all the lines with a |relates_to_position| field to the line which has |position| = |relates_to_position|.

For the above table, this would be

```
|value| |position| |relates_to_position| |type|
100         2             NULL              1
70          6             NULL              2
```

I am quite a newbie in SQL, so I would be glad for help. The database I use is Oracle XE 11. There will only be a single level of relates_to_position, meaning, that if relates_to_position is set, no other line will reference to this line.

Comment: which db/version are you using

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Is there more than a single level of "relates_to"-edness? E.g. could another row have a `relates_to_position` of 7, and if so, what would be the expected result then?

Answer (score 3):

If we only assume 1 level of hierarchy.   If multiple level's of hierarchy this gets more interesting.

```
SELECT A.Value+coalesce(B.Value,0) as Value
     , A.Position
     , A.Relates_to_Position
     , A.Type
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B
  on B.Relates_To_Position = A.Position
WHERE A. Relate_to_Position is null
```

What this does is a self join so it puts related records on the same row.  it then eliminate all those records with a value in relate_to_position as they will be added to a parent row.

we use a LEFT join because not all records will have a related value and we use coalesce to ensure null's are not attempted to be added.  (coalesce takes the first non-null value)

Not sure why you need relates_To_Position returned as it will ALWAYS be null..

Comment: True, I don't need relates_to_position returned. Thank you very much for your help, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have more than one level of hierarchy and they all need to sum up to the root position, then the following ought to do the trick:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 100 VALUE, 2 position, NULL relates_to_position, 1 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 50 VALUE, 6 position, NULL relates_to_position, 2 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 20 VALUE, 7 position, 6 relates_to_position, 3 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10 VALUE, 8 position, 7 relates_to_position, 3 TYPE FROM dual)
SELECT  SUM(VALUE) VALUE,
        root_position position,
        root_type TYPE
FROM    (SELECT value,
                position,
                TYPE,
                connect_by_root(position) root_position,
                connect_by_root(TYPE) root_type
         FROM   sample_data
         CONNECT BY PRIOR position = relates_to_position
         START WITH relates_to_position IS NULL)
GROUP BY root_position,
         root_type;

     VALUE   POSITION       TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
       100          2          1
        80          6          2
```

Comment: :-) You beat me to it this time.

Comment: Feel free to add the recursive subquery factoring way; I never did get the hang of that! *{;-)

Comment: No, I came up with EXACTLY the same solution (I only had rt_pos and rt_type as aliases for the connect_by_root, and I write my solutions in all lower-cap and indent differently, but otherwise the same word for word!) Oh, and I use AS for column aliases. :-)

Comment: I'd write my code all in lower case if I had the choice. Yay for code beautification standards? (aka I'm too lazy to switch off the rules just to post here in lowercase, and then switch them back on afterwards. Or I'd forget to switch them back on... *{;-) )