# SQL: Add values according to index columns only for lines sharing an id

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Yesterday I asked this question: [SQL: How to add values according to index columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550460/sql-how-to-add-values-according-to-index-columns) but I found out that my problem is a bit more complicated:

I have an array like this

---

```
id | value|   position | relates_to_position |type 
19 | 100  |       2    |        NULL         | 1  
19 |  50  |       6    |        NULL         | 2  
19 |  20  |       7    |           6         | 3  
20 |  30  |       3    |        NULL         | 2  
20 |  10  |       4    |           3         | 3
```

From this I need to create the resulting table, which adds all the lines where the relates_to_position value matches the position value, but only for lines sharing the same id!

The resulting table should be

---

```
id | value|   position |type  
19 | 100  |       2    |  1  
19 |  70  |       6    |  2  
20 |  40  |       3    |  2
```

I am using Oracle 11. There is only one level of recursion, meaning a line would not refer to a line which has the relates_to_pos field set.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query will do this:

```
select id, coalesce(relates_to_position, position) as position,
       sum(value) as value, min(type) as type
from t
group by id, coalesce(relates_to_position, position);
```

Comment: How can I keep the lines which have no relates_to_position pointing to them?

Comment: @numberCruncher . . . I believe this query answers your question.  If you have another question, ask it as a question, not a comment.